# Netcat Brute Force Script

Tags: bash, scripting, password, netcat

When I enter `netcat [ip address] [port]` I am asked to enter a password, I actually know the password, it is a date.

However, I would like to create a script that enters the the netcat ip and port number and then goes through a list of dates. I have created a large list of dates that contain the correct password, but I am unsure how to create a script that does what I want. The password (a date) is in ddmmyyyy format. I would really appreciate some help!

Just to make it clear what I am trying to do...

```
1) Script automatically enters: netcat [ip address] [port]
2) Script automatically enters: 01012000
3) Script automatically enters: netcat [ip address] [port]
4) Script automatically enters: 02012000
..................
500) Script automatically enters: netcat [ip address] [port]
501) Script automatically enters: 10082001 (CORRECT PASSWORD) Script end
```

*The script does not need to end when the password is correct, it would be nice, but not necessary. I am trying to just implement the concept first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use brace expansion to create consecutive dates and pipe the input to netcat:

```
#!/bin/bash
for date in 2021-01-{01..31}; do
    echo $date | netcat somehost ...
done
```

Or, a bit more complicated: `for date in 2021-{01-{01..31},02-{01..02}}; do ...`.

Or, read from a file `while read -r date; do ...; done < dates.txt`.

You may need to check how to make netcat quit on time, especially if the remote doesn't close the connection with the commands you gave. There's a few versions of netcat, mine has e.g. this option:

> `-q seconds`
> after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit.